# Sublimetext3 can't use F2 for "Next Book Mark"

Tags: sublimetext3

I have Sublime text 3, and there is a incongruity with "F2" Key:

In menu I can see [image]

But, keybindins says F2 "Next bookmark":

```
{ "keys": ["f2"], "command": "next_bookmark" },
{ "keys": ["shift+f2"], "command": "prev_bookmark" },
{ "keys": ["ctrl+f2"], "command": "toggle_bookmark" },
{ "keys": ["ctrl+shift+f2"], "command": "clear_bookmarks" },
{ "keys": ["alt+f2"], "command": "select_all_bookmarks" },
```

Even if you put these keybindins in "User - Keybindings" **F2 allways show/hide minimap**. I would like to make use of F2 for book marks

Any solution?

Thanks

Comment: https://packagecontrol.io/packages/FindKeyConflicts

Comment: Thanks for the info, with your answer I assume that is not possible to repair this conflict